# Cannot insert data into many relations in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am developing a asp.net web api with angularjs project. My project is actually Hybrid Granularity Authentication. There are several tables in my project but there are only three tables that create problem with insertion. Three tables are AspNetRoles, RolePermission and Roles. And their relationship is:
[image]

There are three roles in Roles table. Employee, Manager and Admin. When admin changes any Role permission then the old Role permission is removed and a new permission is inserted into AspNetRoles table. However, an error occurs when this operation is executed. The error is:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.AspNetRoles'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AspNetRoles'. The duplicate key value is (dbc1ae5c-a8a7-4aa9-b62e-0948e6e2856c)

My Code is to remove and update permission

```cs
    public void SaveUpdateRolePermission(RoleWisePermission rolePermissionList)
    {
        var RoleObject = db.Roles.Where(s => s.Id == rolePermissionList.RoleId).FirstOrDefault();

        if (RoleObject.AspNetRoles.Any())
        {
            foreach (var rolePermission in RoleObject.AspNetRoles.ToList())
            {
                RoleObject.AspNetRoles.Remove(rolePermission);
            }
        }

        foreach (AspNetRoles Role in rolePermissionList.PermissionList)
        {
            RoleObject.AspNetRoles.Add(Role);
        }


        db.SaveChanges();
        db.Dispose();

    } 

    public class RoleWisePermission
    {
        public List<AspNetRoles> PermissionList { get; set; }
        public System.Guid RoleId { get; set; }
    }
```

A problem occurs when `db.saveChanges()`. Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: I think the problem is you are not saving your changes after you remove the roles and before you Add the new ones.

Comment: You should probably separate these transactions.

Comment: I also try to save changes after remove the roles from AspNetRoles. But same problem is continue. @WEI-DBA

Comment: Is there a trigger on that table?

Answer (score 0):

You need first check if the  `RoleObject.AspNetRoles.Add(Role);` exists before add,

or in your code you the object `rolePermissionList.PermissionList` has duplicated itens

Comment: I already removed all the AspNetRoles related with RoleId. So there is no chance to duplicate ant items. And also remember that the problem is occurred even there is no data in Role Permission table.

Comment: And i also check the distinct items of rolePermissionList.PermissionList. And if i  remove data from Role object for specific Role id and then check that there are any AspNetRoles in Role Permission table that return true. How it possible where there are no data in Role Permission Table. Please help me to solve this problems